# How to supress the warning message in the php

Tags: php

I am pretty new to php world. I wrote the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>It joins simple1 and prac1 program together</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if($_POST['user'])
        {
            print "hello,";
            print $_POST['user'];
        }
        else{
        print <<<_HTML_
            <form method="post" action="$_server[PHP_SELF]">
                Your name:<input type="text" name="user">
                </br>
                <input type="submit" value="hello"> 
            </form>
        _HTML_;
        }           
    ?>
</body>
</html>  ---- line 23
```

Getting Error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\php_practice\simple2.php on line 23
```

I have removed all html tags and just kept php tags it worked:

```
<?php
// Print a greeting if the form was submitted
if ($_POST['user']) {
print "Hello, ";
// Print what was submitted in the form parameter called 'user'
print $_POST['user'];
print "!";
} else {
// Otherwise, print the form
print <<<_HTML_
<form method="post" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">
Your Name: <input type="text" name="user">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Say Hello">
</form>
_HTML_;
}
?>
```

Output : Giving proper output but with an warning

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\php_practice\test.php on line 3
```

1. Why it is not working with the previous case? What is going wrong?
2. How to remove or silent the warning message in the second code. It looks bad in the browser.

Comment: It's normally preferable to embed your PHP in your HTML rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The cause of your parse error:

The closing of a `HEREDOC` statement must occur at the beginning of a line with no whitespace before or after.  You have your `_HTML` indented to the same level as the rest of your code, but it must occur at the very first character position of the line.

```
    _HTML_;

// Should be
_HTML_;
```

#### The cause of your `undefined index` warning:

To test if `$_POST['user']` is set, use `isset()`.  That will take care of your `undefined index` error.

```
if(isset($_POST['user']))
```

#### Update: The cause of the `undefined variable _server` notice:

Inside a HEREDOC or double quoted string, you will need to wrap complex variables (arrays, objects) in `{}`.  Also, place quotes around `PHP_SELF`.

```
<form method="post" action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}">
```

Comment: isset has taken care of the warning as well as in the first code removing the beginning whitespace before _HTML_ working fine. But now it is throwing different error:  "Notice: Undefined variable: _server in C:\wamp\www\php_practice\simple2.php on line 14" ..... Line 14 is    <form method="post" action="$_server[PHP_SELF]">

Comment: @user427394 See update above - you'll need to wrap `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in `{}`

Comment: Wrapping within {} didn't help. The strange part is when copy paste the section within <?php .... ?> in a different file and check it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @user427394 I notice now that in the upper part of your post, you use `$_server` incorrectly, and in the lower part you use `$_SERVER`. Case matters, and it must be uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress errors in PHP with an @ before the function name (won't work in this case) or by setting error_reporting to a diffrent value (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

but you should fix the source of the warning instead of suppressing it. In this case there are whitespaces before your *HTML*;